# When do we need `-e` for sed?

Tags: sed

I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010364/156458, and have a question about the `-e` option of sed.

If I am correct, `-e` is used for preceding an inline sed command. But we can specify an inline sed command without `-e`. For example, the following two work the same for me:

```
$ echo foo | sed  's/foo/bar/g'
bar

$ echo foo | sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'
bar
```

It is not like `-f` needed to specify a sed script. When do we need `-e`? In the specific case in the link given at the beginning, why do we need `-e`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically want to use `-e` (possibly along with `-f`) when you want to pass more than one expression as `sed` code.

The expressions given after `-e` and the content of files given after `-f` are concatenated (with newlines) to form the `sed` script. When you want to pass only one literal expression, you can omit the `-e` and pass that expression as the first non-option argument to `sed`.

```
sed -e s/foo/bar/ -f file.sed -e 'a\' -e foo
```

is the same as doing:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/
content of file.sed
a\
foo'
```

Since there are places (like after the `w`/`r`/`#` commands and more depending on the implementations) where you can't use `;` to separate commands, and some where you do need a newline (like that `a` above), using several `-e`s is one way to keep the `sed` command on one line (useful for shells like `csh` that make it awkward to enter multi-line commands, or shells like `ksh` that make it awkward  to *edit* them).

In the case of:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

vs

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

That makes strictly no difference.

Answer (score 6):

This is answered in the man page for sed (`man sed`)

> `-e script`, `--expression=script` add the script to the commands to be executed

And

> If no `-e`, `--expression` [...] option is given, then the first non-option argument is taken as the `sed` script to interpret.  All remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files  are specified, then the standard input is read.

So, if you have only one argument to `sed` it is treated as a `sed` script. If you have more than one you should use `-e` or `--expression` to identify which argument is a `sed` script.

In the case of your specific example, the two alternatives are synonymous.

Comment: Thanks. In the example (the reply and the post it replied to) in the link, I wonder why `-e` solves the problem.

Comment: As indicated in the link, I have no idea why grep is used with sed in the first place!!!

Comment: @Tim the presence or absence of `-e` is a red herring; it makes no difference whatsoever whether one writes `sed 's/replaceme/withthis/g'` or `sed -e 's/replaceme/withthis/g'`. In the [particular situation you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010364/156458) there was definitely something else going on that we weren't able to see from the examples. As for `grep | sed`, there may occasionally be a need for this construct, but mostly it's an unnecessary use of `grep`.

Comment: seems likeliest to me that their "replaceme" wasn't actually `replaceme` but instead contained a forward slash somewhere in it, which `-e` would not help at all. Perhaps they were using double-quotes in reality (and single-quotes for the Question), and the variable's contents had a forward slash.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes. Too many unknowns to be sure, though.